# Checking old password with password column in database

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I need to check the password given by the user in an input and check it. If it's right I'll update the password with new password, if the password is wrong I want to give the user an alert in laravel 5.4.

controller:

```
public function edit(Request $request){

    $user = new User;
    $user = $user->find(1);

            $oldpassword = $request->input('oldpassword');
            $newpassword = $request->input('newpassword');

        //if condition 
        /*if (user()->id == $oldpassword){
            $updatesucess = 1;
        }else {
            $updatesucess = 0;
        }*/


            $user->update(['password' => $newpassword]);
            return back();
        }
```

view:

```
@section('content')
<div class="form">
    <div class="logo-area">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
    </div>
    <form method="POST" action="/edit">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="password" name="oldpassword" placeholder="old Password" required>
        <input type="password" name="newpassword" placeholder="new Password" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Save changes">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `check` method of `Hash` facade ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing))

1. In your controller `file` add Hash facade:

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
   ```
2. Add password check and in case of mismatch handle redirect with an error

   ```
   $user = User::find(1);

   $oldpassword = $request->input('oldpassword');

   if (Hash::check($oldpassword, $user->password)) {
     // redirect back with error
   }
   ```
3. Update user password using `Hash::make`

   ```
    $newpassword = $request->input('newpassword'); 
    $user->update(['password' => Hash::make($newpassword)]);
   ```

Comment: Use Redirect With Flashed Session Data: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel versions>8 this is the best solution.

```
'old_password' => 'required|current_password'
```

You can also specify the api

```
'old_password' => 'required|current_password:web'
```